# How can I change price on changing selecting different from dropdown? (Django)

Tags: javascript, html, django, ajax

**Html**

```
<select class="tranactionID" style="width: 250px;">
            {% for val in productID.list %}
                <option price={{val.Price}} class="price_value" >{{val.AUID}} - {{val.Description}} - {{val.Price}}</option>
                {% endfor %}
          </select>
         
          <div class="pricing">
            <p class="price"><span class="mr-2 price-dc">Rs. </span><span class="price-sale" id='id_price'>Rs. </span></p>
          </div>
```

**Script**

```
<script>
   $(document).on("change", '.price_value', function (event) {
           event.preventDefault();
           console.log($('#id_price').val($(this).children(":selected").attr("price")));

    });
</script>
```

**Problem**
*In the dropdown I have different values from the server and {{val.price}} represents the price of each item. Now what I want is that if I change the option value from the dropdown the price should be updated in the " for price" respectively.*

Comment: here `price_value` should be `tranactionID` and `.val()` should be `.text()`

Comment: this didn't worked for me

Comment: one of the ways you can achieve this is to trigger an ajax request on select, get the price based on the value select and display

Comment: what does work ? did you change that ? See working code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/35tgxw6v/).

Comment: Thanks @Swati it's working on the link u provided.